# Callback not firing while making an HTTP request

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am trying to get the latitude and the longitude as the output by providing the address to a Google API with the URL: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${encodedAddress}.`

The callback executes after 5 minutes of delay and prints: 
`'Unable to connect to the Google service'.`

I've tried running the URL mentioned above in a chrome browser with custom address and it works fine by giving a JSON output but it doesn't seem to work for my app. Here is the code, any help would be appreciated:

```
const request = require('request');
var geocodeAddress = (address, callback) => {

var encodedAddress = encodeURIComponent(address);
console.log(encodedAddress);

request({
    url: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${encodedAddress}`,
    json: true
}, (error,response,body) => {

    if (body.status === 'OK'){

        callback(undefined, {
            address: body.results[0].formatted_address,
            latitude: body.results[0].geometry.location.lat,
            longitute: body.results[0].geometry.location.lng
        });

    } else if (body.status === 'ZERO_RESULTS') {
        callback('Unable to find that address');
    } else if (error) {
        callback('Unable to connect to google service');
    } 
});

}

module.exports.geocodeAddress = geocodeAddress;
```

Comment: Can you provide `encodedAddress`

Comment: I entered 'Pune, India' in command line which encodes to 'Pune%2C%20India'

Comment: if you type 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Pune%2C%20India' it gives JSON output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callback is never called cause you only handle 3 states were there are more. Doing a simple request I got `body.status === 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT'` with no error.

```
const request = require('request');
var geocodeAddress = (address, callback) => {

    var encodedAddress = encodeURIComponent(address);
    console.log(encodedAddress);

    request({
        url: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${encodedAddress}`,
        json: true
    }, (error, response, body) => {

        if (error) {
            callback('Unable to connect to google service');
            return;
        }

        if (body) {

            if (body.status === 'OK') {

                callback(undefined, {
                    address: body.results[0].formatted_address,
                    latitude: body.results[0].geometry.location.lat,
                    longitute: body.results[0].geometry.location.lng
                });

            } else if (body.status === 'ZERO_RESULTS') {

                callback('Unable to find that address');

            } else {
                //handle all the rest here
                console.log(body.status);
                callback(body.status);
            }

        } else {
            //handle all the rest here
            console.log("No body");
            callback("No body");
        }

    });

}

module.exports.geocodeAddress
```

= geocodeAddress;

Comment: I am getting a new error: if (body.status === 'OK'){
                                       ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

Comment: You are right, that 'else condition' takes care of rest of the error cases, I was getting the 'status undefined' error because my system proxy settings were wrongly enabled. Thank you @Stamos